# Qt weird priority for mouse control

Tags: c++, qt, mouse

I use Qt5.7 on Windows 10 to offer a GUI and to control the position of the mouse on the screen. I use SetCursorPos.

However, when a High-level feature of Windows is active, the mouse control stops. For instance, if the Task Manager has the focus, the mouse control stops. The same thing happen if Visual Studio has the focus. This happens if I use MinGW or MSVC compilers.

The exact same program but compiled with Visual Studio doesn't have this problem. I didn't set any special permissions or rights. The mouse control continues if the Task Manager has the focus.

With the program compiled with Qt, if I run the program as administrator (which I want to avoid), there is no problem either, the mouse control continues.

This is not really my field of expertise, would you have any suggestions ?

Thank you very much,

Alex

Comment: Most probably it's just your application inheriting some extra permissions from being launched by VS. What if you compile your application with Visual Studio and launch the generated exe manually?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I thought I tested that but I must have made a mistake. When I run the VS .exe from the release folder its the same problem. I ran a similar program I found on the web and it also had the same problem with the task manager. However, with my program (either Qt or VS), the mouse control also stop when Windows Virtual Keyboard has the focus. However, this program doesn't stop when the Vritual Keyboard has the focus. Is there some way to run the Qt program at a higher level or something ?